# If we increased the frequency of HV-AC lines, could we get atmospheric air to excite and illuminate?

Tags: power, laser, optics, ionization

I had a thought experiment I wanted to run past some experts.

It starts with CFL light bulbs. CFL light bulbs are light bulbs that use ~500 VAC @ ~20 kHz or more to excite a gas in a light vacuum.

High Voltage AC (HVAC) lines will often have 100 kVrms or more, at 60 Hz.

This seems like more than enough to ionize CFL lights, though, the atmosphere is not a CFL.

Working in the principal that above a certain total voltage change, the DE/dt of any electric field determines whether a gas will be ionized, it would seem like increasing the frequency of our HVAC lines could cause a natural lighting of sorts through local ionization.

So with the thoughts as above, my question is as follows; could increasing the frequency of our HVAC lines cause said power lines to illimunate? Could this illumination be maintained without any threat to the lines/people (i.e.: complete dielectric breakdown)?

Comment: Do you still envision the lines performing the function of power transmission? If it did work, the skin effect and energy lost in ionizing the gas would probably make power transmission way less efficient, depending on the frequency.  Then core and AC losses in the transformers and substations would also be an issue.

Comment: @JohnD Sure, but obviously with an incredible increase in power prices :-).

Comment: [Why does public mains power use 50-60 Hz and 100-240 V?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/211262) on the physics stack exchange has some reasons for the use of 50-56 Hz for power transmission.

Comment: I think if you speak with animal species conservators and astronomers they wouldn't be very happy to do this so, why would you be interested in this? Maybe it's just a thought experiment?

Comment: If you *do* have sufficiently high frequency to make the big dE/dt as you say, you can light a low pressure fluorescent tube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHgsQzBKHMc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They already do illuminate and you can see it under certain conditions, the effect is called [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge). For most high voltage lines (I'd say at least 30kV) you can at least hear it as a crackling sound:

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Koronaentladungen_an_Hochspannungsleitung.jpg

Corona discharge happens when electrons ionize the air which, the effect gets more pronounced with higher voltages. It is on a much smaller scale than natural lightning which is much more voltage, I wouldn't consider it dangerous. You might pick up a very small amount of blue/UV light, other than that it wouldn't be bad for an organism. Somebody on the powerline however might be able to get corona discharge coming off of them similar to a telsa coil (low current, high voltage)

Comment: I had no clue that power lines had a corona! This is incredible!

Comment: Pretty cool, eh?

Comment: Birds and many animals can see UV and thus, corona. And it terrifies them (see here: https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/article/power-lines-look-like-terrifying-bursts-of-light-to-animals/)

Comment: Never seen this on any line but it sure looks cool.

Comment: While really cool, this is an unwanted effect on powerlines. It is an outright energy loss, it promotes corrosion, it creates radio noise and it sometimes develops into an arc.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Would increasing the frequency result in more corona discharge?

Comment: It's a moot point, the answer is implicit. If they already illuminate at the frequency that they are running at now then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is not really in the frequency, but in the gas pressure.

In order to create the plasma in CFL lights, you use impact ionization. This means that charge carriers need to reach a certain energy before being able to ionize another atom. This works best when the gas pressure is low and the mean free path becomes longer.

At atmospheric conditions, mean free path is much shorter than in low pressure vapor lamps. So one would need a much higher electric field for sustainable impact ionization. And then, at such high pressure and high charge carrier concentration, once you do set up a glow discharge, it would quickly run away into an arc discharge.

That is why you get stable glow discharges only in low pressure conditions.

Comment: I understand that with low pressures, the longer free path allows more energy to be extracted from the E field gradient. That's easy to see with DC. But would higher frequencies with AC allow only shorter times to accelerate the charge carriers? If so, higher frequencies would inhibit glow discharge. What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: @ttonon You are correct..It is an interesting question in itself. Sometimes RF is deliberately chosen for glow discharges, but it does need an overlaying DC component, for the reasons you state.

Answer (score 4):

> Could this illumination be maintained without any threat to the lines/people (i.e.: complete dielectric breakdown)?

As the other answers (at time of writing) have covered the other aspects ably, I'll concentrate on this point.

No -- as can be seen by any demonstration of a Tesla Coil, high frequencies inevitably cause air to break down into dazzling, chaotic streamers.  We have several consequences:

1. The light output is unstable, flickering as some streamers cool off then new paths are created, etc.
2. The light is harsh, having mostly a bluish color, and considerable UV that would be unsafe for exposure.
3. Ionization of air leads to the ions snapping back together in whatever way is fastest -- we get chemical reactions, most notably the oxidation of oxygen (ozone, O<sub>3</sub>) and nitrogen (N<sub>2</sub>) into NO and NO<sub>2</sub>.  These are quite toxic by themselves, and also further react with water and trace organics to make nitric acid and other smog molecules.

Overall, it would be a very unpleasant, to destructive, way to replace lighting. :)

The other sort of thing you're thinking, though, has been done -- electrodeless glow discharge lamps have been a thing for a long time, though subject to various difficulties that have kept them a fairly minor technology.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_lamp

(This is mostly a physics/chemistry answer, but that's not a bad thing; chemistry is naught but the motion of electrons on small scales, and chemistry and electronics are sister disciplines under the family of physics.  Both go well together.)

Comment: I would add:  4.  Chaotic streamers implies them chaotically finding paths for current to flow through, which seems to me likely to sometimes include linespeople.  5.  Ozone would be emitted, which breaks down organic matter including birds, perhaps wire insulation, linespeople, foliage, wooden power structures, ...

Comment: I think it's pretty clear, any such line would have to be disabled before anyone even approaches it, lol.  Needless to say it wouldn't be useful over any distance, both for losses due to breakdown, and because high frequencies are simply unsuitable for long-distance transmission.